# How to Rotate UIButton by tap and hold (hold - rotate by finger)

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone, iphone-sdk-4.1

I'm noob in ios development. I need some help. I have custom UIButton with picture "arrow", so I need to rotate this button by pressing and moving finger in +360 gr. and -360 gr., like compass arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that makes rotation.

```
-(void)LongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    CGPoint p = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint zero;
    zero.x = self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0;
    zero.y = self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0;

    CGPoint newPoint;

    newPoint.x = p.x - zero.x;
    newPoint.y = zero.y - p.y;
    CGFloat angle;
    angle = atan2(newPoint.x, newPoint.y);
    self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, angle);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In detail, you can custom a rotateView,then:

1: In the delegate method of "`touchesBegan`", get `initialPoint` of finger and `initialAngle`.

2: During "`touchesMoved`",get the `newPoint` of finger:

```
CGPoint newPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
  [self pushTouchPoint:thePoint date:[NSDate date]];
  double angleDif = [self angleForPoint:newPoint] - [self angleForPoint:initialPoint];
  self.angle = initialAngle + angleDif;
  [[imageView layer] setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1)];
```

3: At last, in "`touchesEnded`" you can calculate final `AngularVelocity`.

If anything being confused, for more detail, you can write back.